# Running multiple containers on the same Service Fabric node

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have a windows Service Fabric node with 4 cores and I want to host 3 containerized stateless services on it, where each windows container is allocated 1 core to read a message from a queue and process it. I run some experiments and got these results:

- 1 container running on the node: message takes ~18 sec to be
  processed, avg cpu usage per container: 24.7%, memory usage: 1 GB
- 2 containers running on the node: message takes ~25 sec to be
  processed, avg cpu usage per container: 24.4%, memory usage: 1 GB
- 3 containers running on the node: message takes ~35 sec to be
  processed, avg cpu usage per container: 24.6%, memory usage: 1 GB

I thought that containers are supposedly isolated, and I expected the processing time to be constant at ~18s regardless of the number of containers, but in this case, it seems that adding one container affects the processing time in other containers. Each container is set to use 1 core, so they shouldn't be overstepping to use each other's resources, and cpu is not reaching full utilization. Even if cpu was a bottleneck here, I'd expect that at least 2 containers would be able to run with ~18 sec processing time.

Is there a logical explanation for the results? Isn't it not possible to run multiple containers on the same Service Fabric host without affecting the performance of each when there are enough compute resources? How big could the Service Fabric overhead possibly be when trying to run multiple containers on the same node?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your container is not only using CPU, but also memory and I/O (disk, network), which can also become bottlenecks.

- To see the overhead of SF, run the containers outside of SF and see if it makes a difference.
- Use a machine with more memory, and after that, try using an SSD drive. See if that increases performance.
- To avoid process overhead, consider using a single container and have multiple threads do parallel message processing. Make sure to assign it 3 cores.